# Why can't UUID be just timestamp with a sequential number?

Tags: javascript, database, computer-science, data-science, uuid

I just read the spec of [ulid](https://github.com/ulid/spec) and I don't why it converts timestamp to a complicated string? Can't it just be timestamp with a sequential number?

Comment: That wouldn't be universally unique.

Comment: If I understand right, ulid is not universally unique.

Comment: @Nigiri That depends on what your definition of the word "universally" means.  It is _highly_ unlikely that your application would ever generate the same UUID more than once.

Comment: It doesn't convert a timestamp to a complicated string. It converts a timestamp to a 48-bit number, prepends to `0` bits and then encodes those 50 bits in base32, which is a simple 5bit->1char mapping `00000 -> 0, 00001 -> 1, 01001 -> 9, 01010 -> A` and so on.

Comment: It does this for the reasons mentioned in the link you posted: "Lexicographically sortable!", "No special characters (URL safe)", "efficiency and readability", "Case insensitive".

Answer (score 2):

In fact, a timestamp with a sequential number *might* always be unique.  But that would depend on ensuring the same sequence number is never given out more than once for a given timestamp.  An auto increment column in a database approximates this, keeping track of which values are already in use.

By using a UUID, we can avoid all of these potential problems.  Because of the massive number of potential UUIDs, it is statistically almost impossible that the same UUID would ever be generated more than once.  So, a generated UUID is taken to be always unique, and this is one reason for using a UUID over some other scheme.

Answer (score 1):

A number would be 39 digits long (as there are 10 different digits). Using other chars as well (36?), the ULID is shorter. (`(80 + 24bits) / log²(10) > (80 + 24bits) / log²(32)`).

> with a sequential number

Sequential numbers might work on one machine, but not on multiple ones generating ids at the same time (e.g. distributed database). For sure you could then add a machine identifier (thats what other UIDs do), but then you have to make sure that those machine ids are unique too. Using a very long random part, it is very unlikely that two machines will generate the same random number at the same time (`1 / 2 ** 80`).